# Angular 1.3, $interval stops executing when browser is minimized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, browser, intervals

In Angular 1.3, I am using $interval to submit posts to a Java app running on the server.  The client app is being run from a mobile browser (Safari or Chrome).  As long as the browser is open, this works perfectly.  As soon as the browser is minimized, the $interval stops sending the posts.  The posts must go at a regular interval because they contain the user's physical location which is being tracked by the application.  What is the easiest way to solve this problem?  Does this problem require a websockets solution?

Comment: pretty sure the native `setInterval` that `$interval` uses is what is causing the problem you are seeing. Knowing that, you could probably get around it if you can find another way that doesn't use `$interval`.

Comment: try using $timeout and call self at the end of the function